# How do I keep the cursor style the same WHEN the mouse is held down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, so I know the CSS to change the cursor style in the overall page... That is not the problem. I made a JS program that is a paint program... when you have the mouse held down and have a color selected it paints the paint area of the screen. However, once I hold the mouse down it changes to the I looking cursor (text style it may be called?).

How can I keep the cursor the pointer or default no matter what is happening with the mouse? I tried researching this and nothing I found is working. I do not know JQuery yet, just JS. If anyone has some insight let me know. Please understand I am a beginner with JS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the code you're using to change the cursor in the first place? Sounds like something is overwriting that change.

Comment: i have this so far ::selection {color: #000;  cursor: default;} which takes care of the highlighting and the cursor for any situation EXCEPT when the mouse is being held down. I would like the cursor to stay default when the mouse is held down though.

Comment: Do you have url that we could see what is happening or perhaps you could create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
'your element':active {
   cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not seem to correct the problem when the mouse is being held down. Thanks though!